# Enumerating Independent Sets of Size $t=\Theta(n)$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let $i_t(G)$ denote the number of independent sets of size $t$.

There is a bounds $i_t(G)$ for $t = \Theta(n)$(https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.3060.) in terms of minimum degree of $G$.

Q. Is there any current results related to enumerating algorithm for independent sets of size $t = \Theta(n)$?

Comment: how's (section $2$ of) [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3242.pdf)?